# does pyinstxtractor extract imported .py file that import by main as well?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable

Hi I am new to python and want to understand how to interact with exetuable and pyc/py file.

Suppose I compile my executable `main.exe` using `pyinstaller`. With source files `main.py` and `demo.py`
in my `main.py` I have imported `demo.py as dm`

When I decompile my executable `main.exe` using `pyinstxtractor`. I was only able to get `main.pyc`, it doesn't seem I am getting something like `demo.pyc` or any file with `demo.py` source code.

I wonder if I am doing it wrong or it suppose to be like this, any thing would help.

Tried reading many posts online and still don't have any idea.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I will say, as author of a now-unsupported [competing tool](https://github.com/charles-dyfis-net/pydeinstaller), it's _easier_ to extract the other modules than the main.